My action button doesn't work as expected
I have a component called index.blade.php which has a button with a wire:click="newTask" that calls the public function newTask on the Livewire/Index.php, but for some reason it doesn't work, I have tried other solutions that worked on another similar component of user creation but it didn't work as well.
index.blade.php
<div class="flex flex-row">
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center p-5 rounded-lg bg-white mr-2">
    <img class="w-[60px] rounded-full" src="{{ $user_profile_picture_url }}" alt="profile picture">
    {{ $user_name ?? 'Convidado' }}
    &nbsp;
    <button
      wire:click="newTask"
      class="px-6 py-2 bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-blue-900 text-white font-semibold rounded-full shadow-md hover:from-blue-900 hover:to-blue-600 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
    >
      Nova
    </button>
    <button
      wire:click="logoutUser"
      class="px-6 py-2 bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-blue-900 text-white font-semibold rounded-full shadow-md hover:from-blue-900 hover:to-blue-600 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out"
    >
      Sair
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-col items-center pl-10 pr-10 pt-5 pb-10 rounded-lg bg-white">
    @if (session()->has('data.user_id'))
      <livewire:datatable-tasks :user_id="$user_id" data_type="tasks" title="Tarefas atribuídas a você"/>
    @else
      <h1 class="font-bold text-xl">Bem Vindo ao TodoToday, sua aplicação para criar lista de tarefas super organizadas.</h1>
      <span>Faça seu <a href="user/login" class="text-blue-500">Login</a> para registrar suas tarefas.</span>
      <h1>Ainda não tem uma conta? faça seu <a class="text-blue-500" href="/user/create">Registro</a></h1>
      <h1>ou</h1>
      <a href="/task/create" class="px-6 py-2 bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-blue-900 text-white font-semibold rounded-full shadow-md hover:from-blue-900 hover:to-blue-600 transition-colors">Criar sem guardar</a>
    @endif
  </div>
</div>

Index.php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;

class Index extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;
    public $user_id;
    public $user_name;
    public $user_email;
    public $user_profile_picture_url; 

    public function createWithoutLogin()
    {
        session()->flash('data', [
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'user_name' => $this->user_name,
            'user_email' => $this->user_email,
            'user_profile_picture_url' => $this->user_profile_picture_url
        ]);

        return redirect()->to('/task/create');
    }

    public function newTask()
    {
        session()->flash('data', [
            'user_id' => $this->user_id,
            'user_name' => $this->user_name,
            'user_email' => $this->user_email,
            'user_profile_picture_url' => $this->user_profile_picture_url
        ]);

        return redirect()->to('/task/create');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $this->user_id = session('data.user_id');

        if ($this->user_id) {
            $this->user_name = session('data.user_name');   
            $this->user_email = session('data.user_email');
            $this->user_profile_picture_url = session('data.user_profile_picture_url');
        }

        return view('livewire.index');
    }
}

create.blade.php
<div>
    <form action="">
        <div class="flex flex-col items-center pl-10 pr-10 pt-5 pb-10 rounded-xl bg-white">
            <h1 class="text-xl">Registre-se</h1>
            <span class="mb-5">Já é cadastrado? <a class="text-blue-500" href="/user/login">Entre</a></span>
            @error('name') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            <input wire:model="name" type="text" placeholder="Nome" class="w-full px-4 py-2 bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-400 focus:border-transparent shadow-sm transition-shadow mb-2">
            @error('email') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            <input wire:model="email" type="email" placeholder="Email" class="w-full px-4 py-2 bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-400 focus:border-transparent shadow-sm transition-shadow mb-2">
            @error('password') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            <input wire:model="password" type="password" placeholder="Senha" class="w-full px-4 py-2 bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-400 focus:border-transparent shadow-sm transition-shadow mb-2">
            @error('confirm_password') <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
            <input wire:model="confirm_password" type="password" placeholder="Confirmar Senha" class="w-full px-4 py-2 bg-gray-100 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-blue-400 focus:border-transparent shadow-sm transition-shadow mb-2">

            <button wire:click.prevent="createUser" class="px-6 py-2 bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-blue-900 text-white font-semibold rounded-full shadow-md hover:from-blue-900 hover:to-blue-600 transition-colors">Registrar-se</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

Create.php
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\User;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Livewire\Component;

class Create extends Component
{
    public $name;
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $confirm_password;

    protected $user_id;

    public function createUser()
    {
        $validated_data = $this->validate(
          rules: [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:45'],
            'email' => ['required', 'email', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6'],
            'confirm_password' => ['required', 'same:password'],
          ],
          messages: [
            'name.required' => 'Nome é obrigatório!',
            'name.max' => 'Nome inválido! (Máx 45 carac.)',
            'email.required' => 'Email é obrigatório!',
            'email.email' => 'Email inválido!',
            'email.unique' => 'Email já em uso!',
            'password.required' => 'Senha é obrigatório!',
            'password.min' => 'Senha inválida! (Min 6 carac.)',
            'confirm_password.required' => 'Confirme a senha!',
            'confirm_password.same' => 'Senhas não condizem!',
          ],
        );

        User::create([
            'name' => $validated_data['name'],
            'email' => $validated_data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($validated_data['password']),
            'profile_picture_url' => 'https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/72869261?v=4',
        ]);

        return redirect()->to('/user/login');
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.user.create');
    }
}

I tried to put the component with only nested nodes and tried to put my button inside a form tag just like the second component I mentioned, I need it to call the function and do the redirect.

The action of the first example is called as expected, you can verify this thing using a dump() in the action. I may suppose that the problem is the redirect, since with Livewire this is a bit dfferent than the regular Laravel redirect. In fact with Livewire the redirect is managed in the frontend side and the methods and the helpers do not return anything. Take a look here and if you want to the vendor/livewire/livewire/src/Features/SupportRedirects/HandlesRedirects.php source code

It appears that the link associated with the word here in last sentencence has  been lost. The link is: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/redirecting#basic-usage
